# Why can't I add an Input widget from template?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I'm simply trying to create an Input widget. I can add one using the Sprite template, but not the Input template. Why?

**Can Add To Main Panel!**
[image]

**Doesn't work :(**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A font must be selected first.

[image]

Comment: It would probably help the next guy if you elaborated a bit. ie Where/how did you select a font? (It is not shown in your screen shots)